# How to copy a collection from one DB to another in mLab?

Tags: mongodb, collections, mlab, heroku-toolbelt, heroku-cli

I need to transfer data from one collection COLx in a database DB1 in mLab (/Heroku) to a new collection COLx in a new database DB2, in a separate application. What is the way to do that?
After searching the net and reading about mongoexport and mongoimport, I thought this was the way to go. But when trying I got errors like:

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Obviously I must not be doing the right thing.

Any advice would be very welcome.

Comment: Check if you can run MongoDB Aggregation with [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) operator

Comment: This $merge(aggregation) thing seems to be quite powerful, but it does not seem clear to me (precise syntax to use) how I can use this to copy say collectionOne to collectionTwo. And also in which context is it supposed to be used? Command line? Javascript?

Comment: Can you check please MongoDB version? If 4.2 is supported, take a look my answer. You can both in shell / your app

Comment: When I run "mongo --version". I get "MongoDB shell version: 3.2.7".

Comment: It seems I need to use mongoexport and mongoimport. But I don't how to use that.

Answer (score 0):

For MongoDB v4.2, you may copy data from `DB1.COL1` to `DB2.COL2` with [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) operator.

```
//DB1
db.runCommand(
    { aggregate : "COL1", pipeline : [
        { $merge : {
            into: { db: "DB2", coll: "COL2" },
            on: "_id",
            whenMatched: "replace",
            whenNotMatched: "insert"
        }}]
    }
);
```